# uncaught TypeError: reduceInitial is not a function

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have an error that I cannot understand. It looks like I forgot to load a library but I've gone through all the available d3 libraries I can't see which library has reduceInitial as a function.

I use:

d3 v3.5.17

dc v2.0.5

crossfilter v1.3.14

jquery v3.6.1

d3-color v1.4.1

d3-format v1.4.5

d3-interpolate v1.4.0

d3-scale v2.2.2

d3-scale.chromatic v1.5.0

d3-time v1.1.0

d3 v2.3.0

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Relevant question, something that is likely to come up for many users of this library. Why are people down/close-voting this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the third parameter to [group.reduce()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce) and it expects a function.

You probably neglected to pass this parameter, so it's trying to call `undefined` as a function.